# Apache Basic Auth not working in customer network

Tags: apache-2.2, http-basic-authentication

I'm having trouble, letting a customer see a site that is locked with a simple Apache Basic Auth password file.

It works in every browser on Mac, Windows and in our network. Even the customer get's it working at home, but not in his office.

What could possibly go wrong here? Some Proxy caching something?

UPDATE: My config that has always worked in projects either in .htaccess or vhost config

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Customer - Project"
AuthUserFile /mnt/drbd0/www/staging.hostname.com/site/include/passwords
Require user staging.project
```

UPDATE2: And here's the relevant part from the error.log

```
[Tue Mar 12 11:15:54 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 11:16:15 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 11:16:39 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 11:17:03 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 11:30:00 2013] [error] [client ] user staging.project: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
[Tue Mar 12 11:30:17 2013] [error] [client ] user staging.project: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
[Tue Mar 12 11:35:25 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 12:34:25 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 12:34:43 2013] [error] [client ] user download not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 13:05:08 2013] [error] [client ] user download not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 13:05:44 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 13:05:54 2013] [error] [client ] user download not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 13:06:03 2013] [error] [client ] user download not found: /
[Tue Mar 12 17:10:29 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Wed Mar 13 08:54:21 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Wed Mar 13 08:54:36 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Wed Mar 13 08:54:50 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Wed Mar 13 08:54:52 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
[Wed Mar 13 08:55:06 2013] [error] [client ] user  not found: /
```

Answer (score 0):

The authorization requires the user's browser to tell the server what domain name it is requesting.  It looks like your customer's browser is not correctly sending that information.  Make sure that the customer isn't using a proxy.  Watch the access logs as the customer tries to hit an unprotected part of the site.

Also consider taking down the password authentication for a few minutes (put up a dummy html page in the same directory if you have to) and see if the customer can get to the page when there is no authentication.